# BASH named pipe locking up

Tags: bash, locking, named-pipes

I don't understand why this is happening.  I've been working with this same command for a long time and now, suddenly, it's started locking up.

```
mkfifo ./pipe
echo "test" >./pipe
```

What can I do to stop this from locking up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read from the FIFO.

Comment: oh, that's right...  thank you.   I don't know what I was thinking.  I need to  echo woot>./woot &

Answer (score 2):

It's not locked up.  It's waiting for something to read from the pipe.  Execute

```
cat < ./pipe
```

in another window, and it will print out the `test` string you put into the pipe, and then your `echo` will exit.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and the same... huh... thinking error...

I solved my problem here, and discovered [An excellent article about named pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) I wanted to share with everybody wanting to use "rightly" named pies.

Don't forget to read the comments ;)

Enjoy !